# multiple sub domain with multiple ssl certificate { SSL and apache }

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a dedicated server which is pointed to the domain 
`www.domain1.com`.  I bought ssl sertificates for my domain x1.domain1.com which cost $10 
so I bought ssl certificates for all sub domains, since wildcard certificate is too costly.

When i restart apache, the x1.domain1.com is getting  set to the ssl certificate 
on x2.domain1.com it shows an "untrusted warning" that this certificate is valid for some other domain.  I checked the certificate itself, and it shows a domain of x1.domain1.com,
that is the certificicate of x1.domain1.com

How can I get multiple SSL vhosts set up?

My config file is

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin1@server1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/htm2/
        ServerName x1.domain1.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/server.key </VirtualHost>



 <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin2@server1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/htm/
        ServerName x2.domain1.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/l/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/l/server.key  </VirtualHost>
```

the problem is i am having a single dedicated ip : 141.XX.XX.X but when i go to  https://x1.domain1.com  in chrome or firefox latest , the certificate works , but when i go to https://x2.domain1.com . it shows a certificate untrustness , and says conform trust of certificate as this certificate is for another domain , i viewed the certificate and saw it as  certificate of x1.domain1.com

i want both of the sites to be browsed like

> ```
> https:\\x1.domain1.com
> https:\\x2.domain1.com
> ```

with out any port or any thing ... what settings should i alter in the above config to attain this , what is the trouble which cause x2.domain1.com to show certificate of x1..domain and also how can i redirect

http:\x1.domain1.com to  https:\x1.domain1.com  with out using htaccess , if by htaccess then how ?

also how to redirect

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz After editing for spelling and formatting, I added the question that you and I both answered :)

Comment: Do you get the content for `x1` or `x2` after you click through the cert warning? Does your client browser support SNI?  Provide the output of `apachectl -S`; do you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` configured?

Answer (score 1):

SNI isn't supported by almost half of current Internet browsers. So the server has to decide which certificate to send to the client knowing only the port the client connected to. If you need to serve two different certificates, probably your best choice is to use two different ports. Alternatively, you can use a service that lets you put both names in the same certificate. (StartSSL, for example, lets you put any hosts for any domains you validate in any certificates you issue in any combination.)

Comment: It's mostly just browsers on the Microsoft crypto APIs under XP - that's well under half these days, isn't it?

Comment: Last I checked (about four months ago) it was just under half. (Browsers that didn't support SNI, mostly IE under XP, but others too.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to either bind your vhosts to a different IP address or bind to a different port.

The problem is that you can't have two SSL hosts on the same IP+PORT because the hostname can't be determined as it is part of the encrypted content.  So it picks one of the vhosts and delivers that (typically the first vhost) http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

As David Schwartz said, you can also put all the names in a single certificate.  In x509 parlance, that is the `SubjectAlternateName` field.

Comment: can i merge the two different ssl certificates into a single one ? , then how ?

Comment: SubjetAlternateName is part of the certificate signing request (CSR).  You would have to generate a new CSR with both names in it.